# htaccess use of Order Deny,Allow

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using Order Deny,Allow in my .htaccess file, without success. IP's I need to prevent access to are going right through with no troubles. I read that as of Apache 2.4 Order Deny,Allow would no longer work; first is that factual and second if so what has replaced it? I cannot access my httpd.conf file, so Require and Require not is not an option for me.

I only have access to .htaccess, how can I accomplish banning by ip or if no longer possible, redirecting by ip. Below is a snipit of my Order Deny,Allow if it matters.  Thanks in advance!

---

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 123.125.71.*
Deny from 123.125.71.121.some.domain.com
Deny from some.domain.com
Allow from All
```

---

(as you can see, I'm attempting to block the same ip, in various formats but no matter the format, the traffic continues to go through.)

Comment: What version of apache ard you using?

Comment: I"m unable to determine, however I do see where further in the htaccess the wm prior to me is using RewriteRule rules. is there a simple RewriteRule I could add to push the undesired ip to a 403 or specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push the undesired ip to 403 ,you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^00\.00\.00\.00$
 RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Replace **00.00.00.00** with your undesired ip address.

To ban multiple ipaddress, you can add multiple conditions seprated by a [OR] flag to your rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^00\.00\.00\.00$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^00\.00\.00\.00$
 RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: beautiful, thank you very much for your help. I'm testing that now...  one last questions, some of access is like this:   d27-96-82-165.evv.wideopenwest.com   how would I express such?

Comment: You can do that using %{HTTP_REFERER} Variable. 

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^host$
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]**

Comment: perfect. much appreciated!